Ввод имени и фамилии пользователем
Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь должен был вводить и имя и фамилию, а в случае если что-то из этого не введено, то юзер получал бы сообщение об ошибке.
Пишу для консоли(ConsoleApp), сам не смог

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

полезно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/264178

Ну вы хоть какой-то код начали писать?

Не совсем понятно, какой пользователь должен вводить, а какой юзер получать.

Про пользователя и юзера - да, это такой тонкий сарказм. Смысл его в том, что техническая документация (а вопрос подпадает под эту категорию) должна быть консистентная. Какое-либо понятие должно обозначаться одним термином, и наоборот.

По запросу "I need simple c# app to user providing his name and surname and return error if any of these is absent" Copilot выдал готовый код:
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter your surname: ");
        string surname = Console.ReadLine();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(surname))
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Both name and surname must be provided.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {name} {surname}!");
    }
}

Это я к тому, что можно было бы и самому запросить.
Обновление
На русском тоже работает "Мне нужно простейшее приложение на c#, которое запрашивает у пользователя имя и фамилию и возращает ошибку, если что-либо из этого отсутствует":
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Введите имя: ");
        string firstName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Введите фамилию: ");
        string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: Имя и фамилия обязательны для ввода.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Здравствуйте, {firstName} {lastName}!");
        }
    }
}

Чтобы не только Copilot:
static void Main() {
    string GetNonEmptyInput(string prompt) {
        string input = "";
        Console.Write($"Enter your {prompt} name: ");
        while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input = Console.ReadLine()))
            Console.Write($"Error: {prompt} name cannot be empty.\r\nTry again: ");
        return input;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {GetNonEmptyInput("first")} {GetNonEmptyInput("last")}");
}


май бэд, запрашивал, но только на русском, стоило догадаться на англ поискать. спасибо

да, проблема скорее в том, что я плохо формулирую вопросы, как вы могли заметить)). пойду за одно русский подучу)) спасибо.

@saidrajabov, чем короче запрос тем больше вариантов. Русский у вас корректный вполне.

оке. благодарю вас.

Copilot только, а не Copylot

Э-э-э... ответы от чатгопоты запрещены же.

@AlexanderPetrov Это не ответ от чатгопоты, а про ответ от чатгопоты - две большие разницы, как говорят в Одессе.

Для проверки ввода имени и фамилии, можно использовать цикл, который проверяет, не является ли введённая строка пустой. Если строка пустая, выводится сообщение об ошибке, и программа продолжает запрашивать ввод, пока пользователь не введёт корректное значение. Это достаточно базовый, но наглядный пример для вас - валидации
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string firstName = GetNonEmptyInput("Enter your first name: ", "Error: First name cannot be empty.");

        string lastName = GetNonEmptyInput("Enter your last name: ", "Error: Last name cannot be empty.");

        Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {firstName} {lastName}!");
    }

    //DRY полезно почитать => https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself
    static string GetNonEmptyInput(string prompt, string errorMessage)
    {
        string input = "";
        while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            Console.Write(prompt);
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
            }
        }
        return input;
    }
}


Вы, кстати, видите, что оба цикла практически одинаковые, только с разной переменной работают и разную надпись выводят? Так и напрашивается вынос общего кода в отдельную функцию.

мне хотелось разделить, чтоб как можно базово и наглядно было. а так то конечно можно и рефакторинг сделать

Не знаю, по мне наоборот от копипасты понятность страдает, потому что больше кода читать приходится )

Нас так учили))) писать на листке все по несколько раз,(то есть каждое действие поэтапно, даже если оно повторяется) а потом переписывать понемногу уменьшая код, а потом уже в программу писать

Ну, так то методика норм. Повторенье - мать ученья. Но мне уже глаза режет. Я много кода рефакторю, поэтому сразу такое вижу %)

Тонким пёрышком в тетрадь буквы разные писать учат в школе. "писать на листке все по несколько раз" - это ошибки по нескольку раз.

@rotabor, точнее  сказать "каждое действие") ну ту уж как учили‍♀️//может тут еще, есть мысль, что, когда пишешь второй раз (причем на а4) тоже действие видишь ошибку(?)

Есть такое, но в результате лучше устранять ошибки в одной функции, чем искать повторы по тексту.

@rotabor, это бесспорно истина
